# How to create Dotnet Core WebApi endpoint returning a PDF that works in Swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I have a WebApi method returning a FileStreamResult containing a PDF.

This works as supposed when using PostMan to retrieve the PDF. But when looking at the API using Swagger, the Download file link returns a broken file. Almost double in size, it seems like the file presented by Swagger is UTF-8, and in PostMan is returned in ANSI byte format.

But not sure how to validate.

In Web Api I use ProducesResponseOfType to tell Swagger which data is returned - are there any way to tell that it is an "application/pdf" byte stream that is returned?

Or is there just another way of making it work.

My Api method is pretty much as below - some details left out for clarity.

```
    [HttpPost("JobReports", Name = "GetJobReports")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof( ?WHAT_DO_I_ENTER_HERE? ), 200)]
    public IActionResult GetJobReports([FromServices]IQueryJobs jobs,
                                       [FromServices]JobReportGenerator generator,
                                       [FromBody]List<string> jobsToReport)
    {
            FileStreamResult fileStreamResult = generator.GetJobReports(jobs, jobsToReport);

            if (fileStreamResult == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                return fileStreamResult;
            }
    }
```

I hope someone has been here before, I can't figure out how to tell Swagger that the 200 result is a bytestream containing application/pdf data.

If any questions to my explanation let me know.

Best regards
/Anders